# Organizing months chronologically in ggplot barplot

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm having trouble organizing a plot by chronological month as opposed to alphabetically, and the other questions asked here haven't answered it.

I'm working with the us_perm_visas.csv dataset from www.kaggle.com
https://www.kaggle.com/nsharan/h-1b-visa

To make this specific plot, I made the following df in dplyr called "certjob":

```
certjob <- visas %>% 
  select(decision_date,case_status,country_of_citzenship,employer_city,
     employer_name,employer_state,application_type,naics_2007_us_title)
certjob <- certjob %>% 
mutate(month = month(decision_date),
     months = months(decision_date)) %>% 
arrange(month)
```

I know I should learn how to factor, but hey.  This results in a written month column, and a numerical month column.

Here is my plot:

```
#plot cert case status by month
status <- ggplot(certjob,aes(x=month,fill=case_status)) +
geom_bar(alpha = 0.85) +
labs(title = "Case Status by Month",
   subtitle = "Visa statuses by month 2011-2013",
   x = "Month",y = "Num Cases") +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("#8ec127","#f47835","#d41243","#a200ff")) +
theme_wsj(base_size = 8) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1,size = 6),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 6,angle = -45),
    axis.title = element_text(size = 10),
    legend.title = element_blank(), legend.box.spacing = unit(.1,"cm"),
    legend.key.size = unit(.2,"cm"), legend.position = "top",
    legend.key.width = unit(0.8,"cm"),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 16),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 10))
```

And it looks like this:

[ggplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZtHK.png)

How can I get the months to arrange by the order they are in the arranged plot?  They still come through alphabetically.

Thanks!

Benjamin

Comment: Use `month = month(decision_date, abbr=FALSE)` to get numeric values that will sort properly. There is also a built-in `month.abb` variable that you could use with `order`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this is definitely a situation where using a factor is going to make things easier:

```
certjob <- certjob %>% 
  mutate(month = factor(
    month(decision_date, label = FALSE),   # thing you're converting
    1:12,                                  # values it could take
    labels =                               # how they should appear
      c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr",
      "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug",
      "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"),
    ordered = TRUE))                       # does what it says on the tin
```